# Cocos2d v3 examples

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a little game created with Sprite Kit and now I'm trying to recreate it with Cocos2d. I found that now Cocos2d has a new version with chipmunk physics integrated and I'm trying to find some example projects. I need examples created in Xcode, not in the SpriteBuilder and with some physics. I would be very grateful if someone provide some links!

Comment: Just google it. its easy to find. try maniacdev or Ray Wenderlich site. I found a lot of examples some months ago.

Comment: https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fbufordtaylor%2FTower-Defense--cocos2d&ei=yXzkVJ3OLYy_ggTHu4P4BQ&usg=AFQjCNELKuj-xnc8p5zim641KOSuq3g-tw&sig2=oAiD0O94vzY3by3x3D-_rg&bvm=bv.85970519,d.cWc

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira Are you sure that you are talking about v3 version? It was released not long time ago.

Comment: I am found Tower defende demo game in v3. in october/november I dont remember. I will try to found the link. or git to share.

Answer (score 2):

The Cocos2D guys really prefer that new projects are created using SpriteBuilder as it sets up an entire Xcode project with all the correct header search paths, compile switches and so on for Cocos2D itself and its dependencies.

Also SpriteBuilder can update Cocos2D to new versions which is not trivial to do manually.

There's a [guide on the forums about how to minimise your interaction with SpriteBuilder](http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/installing-cocos2d-swift/15916) to from a small amount to basically nil.

That said if you absolutely want to exorcise SpriteBuilder for some reason you can [try this Github project](https://github.com/slembcke/UnofficialCocos2DTemplate), which is an unofficial template that comes with a rename script, and Cocos2D as a submodule.